# Fix table thead in IE11 while maintaining width

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fixed

I have a table, and I want to fix the header on it, for Google Chrome, Firefox ... etc I use `position: sticky`, and it works perfectly without any issue.

But in the hell of developers (Internet Explorer 11), it's doesn't work, so, I try to use `position: fixed`, but it gets lost the width of `thead`. I try to use `width: 100%` but with no results.

I try another solution: use `position: fixed` in `th`, it works, but the problem is one on top of one, is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exact code you are using because you did not post the sample code.

You can try to refer to this example that may help to fix the issue for the IE 11 browser.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
         }
         thead {
         text-align:left;
         display: table;
         float: left;
         width: 100%;
         }
         thead tr {
         display: table-row;
         width: 100%;
         }
         tbody {
         display: block;
         height: 120px;
         overflow: auto;
         float: left;
         width: 100%;
         }
         tbody tr {
         display: table;
         width: 100%;
         }
         tbody tr {
         height: 18px;
         }
         tbody td {
         padding:1px 8px;
         }
         th, td {
         text-align: left;
         width: 25%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>head</th>
               <th>head</th>
               <th>head</th>
               <th>head</th>
               <th style="width:0px;"></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td>row</td>
               <td style="width:0px;"></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

If the issue persists then please try to share the sample code with the snapshot of the issue. It can really help us to understand the issue in a better way. We will try to check it and try to provide suggestions for it.